# Rotate and zoom entire 2d scene

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I'm currently working on a Final Fantasy like game, and I'm at the point where I'm working on the effect when switching from world map to battles.  I wanted a zoom-in while rotating effect, I was thinking of simply animating a transformation matrix that would be passed to SpriteBatch.Begin, but my problem is when I rotate, the rotation origin is the top left of my entire scene and it doesn't "zoom-in" centered.  I saw that you could specify a rotation origin on SpriteBatch.Draw but that sets it per sprites and I want to rotate the entire scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform you are looking for is this:

```
Matrix Transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Position)
   * Matrix.CreateScale(scale)
   * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(angle) 
   * Matrix.CreateTranslation(GraphisDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Center);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, I didn't realize that you could have more than one translation that reacted differently depending on where they were in the equation, thanks!